# How to show prompt message when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, refresh, prompt

I work on Javascript and I have a simple page.I need to prompt message appear when user want to refresh the page(F5, so on). Is there any method to do so? 
I have tried to use method="post", but because I dont submit anything in my page it doesnt work at all.
Most of the time users want to disable prompt message, but what to do if I want to appear it?
Alert message?
Any ideas?

Comment: @rene You were faster finding a duplicate than I writing this short answer. :)

Comment: @insertusernamehere sorry, give me a call next time and I'll move on...:)  Nice demo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window.onbeforeunload`. The user will be prompted your message and he has the possibility to stay or to leave.

**JavaScript**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return "Don't leave";
};
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/k8gHP/)

Learn more on the MDN [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload)