# how to detect a page refresh in react to perform function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I would like to detect a refresh page (f5 or the refresh button in the browser) in react in order to perform function.
Basically i would like to call an API when the refresh is pushed and to call this API, i need some state value.
Does someone has an idea how to do that?
Thanks

EDIT:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect called");
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleEndConcert);
     return () => {
      // hit endpoint to end show
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleEndConcert);
      //handleEndConcert();
    }
  }, []);

  const handleEndConcert = () => {
    console.log('Stop this');
    console.log(selectedFile);
  }
```

Comment: I think you are looking this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18704284/12656448. User will see your massage in prompt.

Comment: thanks.  is there a way to also trigger a function if the user decide to close the page ?

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64966559/is-there-a-function-like-componentwillunmount-that-will-fire-before-the-page-i/64967211#64967211

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, which I realized is similar to my linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64966559/is-there-a-function-like-componentwillunmount-that-will-fire-before-the-page-i/64967211#64967211) I reread what you are actually asking for.

If I understand your question/issue, you are trying to invoke a function when the component unmounts but has access to the latest state. You can use a react ref and a second effect hook to capture state updates.

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = React.useState(....);

const selectedFileRef = React.useRef(selectedFile); // ref to store state value

React.useEffect(() => {
  selectedFileRef.current = selectedFile; // save selectedFile state value to ref
}, [selectedFile]);

...

useEffect(() => {
  const handleEndConcert = () => {
    console.log('Stop this');
    console.log(selectedFileRef.current); // <-- access current ref value
  }

  console.log("use effect called");

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleEndConcert);

  return () => {
    // hit endpoint to end show
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleEndConcert);
  }
}, []);
```